# Parsing a JSON request from external aplication

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an external application posting a JSON request to my application. I get the following JSON:

```
POST /passou HTTP/1.1^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate^M
Connection:      Keep-Alive^M
Content-Length:  1802^M
Content-Type:    application/json^M
Cookie:          XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkhqbXFpcEZ2NW1qakhma040eHM5OVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVklUMTZYbjk5azF5cXlKR0FCQU9GcEthajZqXC9aVjhLTmdsUlwvanRadTF5RTgxTmZ6YzBDQzVRWk5PTVB3YjBaRlArWXhBRlgzdmtJT0xNXC9BeE5oR0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjMyNWRhNDUzYmE1NDQ0MjMyNjg2ZTY4NDQyYjdlMDVlNjliZWM0Y2E3ZTI3NDQ1ZWYwMjBjMGNhODMzMzhiNjEifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZOWGc4M0ViN0hCRWc2alNkR3dJUHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNExjWDZSWEtKZ3ZSWGFRRHBUOG1EYU9hS2N4b2ZnQ1ViYjBDV1RGV0JMU2prb3dQY1lkalhzbWsrSmtJZkIyTWZPTUlTak45cWpLZHdnZmhrTnYxZ3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc2ODZhMDBhZTY5NzhkYjU4Y2VlNGRjZmNiNDlkZjM4OTVlNjMyMmY0MjQ1ODBmYWRkMzY3MGIwYWNkNjI5NjMifQ%3D%3D^M
Host:            teste.dx7^M
User-Agent:      Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.7.0_79)^M
^M
{"version":"2.0","secret":"123","type":"DevicesSeen","data":{"apMac":"00:18:0a:24:00:d0","apFloors":["Terreo"],"apTags":["","Rui","Terreo",""],"observations":[{"ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":-27.591731402769064,"lng":-48.493424756868876,"unc":30.575295563671613,"x":[39.95044703554812],"y":[12.458059471638961]},"seenTime":"2017-08-18T19:58:16Z","ssid":null,"os":"iOS","clientMac":"d8:bb:2c:79:24:9e","seenEpoch":1503086296,"rssi":10,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Apple"},{"ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":-20.36849699812889,"lng":-56.671748659254035,"unc":3311048.709703039,"x":[-1029790.6265194623],"y":[-482370.5916992783]},"seenTime":"2017-08-18T19:57:59Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"68:c4:4d:59:28:a8","seenEpoch":1503086279,"rssi":11,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Motorola Mobility LLC, a..."},{"ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":-27.591760424025242,"lng":-48.49346321647525,"unc":15.882821701125632,"x":[41.68557674077884],"y":[7.795381645650792]},"seenTime":"2017-08-18T19:58:08Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"f4:f5:24:b5:77:23","seenEpoch":1503086288,"rssi":14,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Motorola Mobility LLC, a..."},{"ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":-27.57610415465702,"lng":-48.51125030308867,"unc":3735355.6769782603,"x":[-2192.503073679766],"y":[-1043.3792964455843]},"seenTime":"2017-08-18T19:58:08Z","ssid":null,"os":"Android","clientMac":"50:55:27:af:71:67","seenEpoch":1503086288,"rssi":7,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"LG Electronics (Mobile..."},{"ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":-10.41563888340804,"lng":-67.94045451135523,"unc":4288150.094385385,"x":[-2448783.397841856],"y":[-1147028.4594821092]},"seenTime":"2017-08-18T19:58:13Z","ssid":null,"os":"Nexus","clientMac":"40:88:05:97:3d:90","seenEpoch":1503086293,"rssi":15,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Motorola Mobility LLC, a..."}]}}
```

I am trying to get rid of the http headers but without success.

I tried:

```
public function passou_usuario(Request $request) {
    $apMac = collect($request->data)->toArray();
    foreach ($apMac as $t) {
        if ($t == '00:18:0a:24:0a:20') {
            $fp = fopen("/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/teste/public/log.log", "a");
            fwrite($fp, $request. PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fp);
        }
        return 'ok';
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, I ended up splitting the request by `\n` which puts the JSON data as the last item in the array

Comment: Is this data from `php://input`?

Comment: Have you tried `$request->all()`?

Comment: Your code works well. What's not working? I have new records in log file. Does your web-server have rights to write into it?

Comment: @CharlieHeflin How did you do that? I tried getting the last line, put it into an array and then tried to get data properties but no success.

Comment: @Roots in php `$headers = explode("\n", $response); $json = end($headers);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be having to parse HTTP headers out of the request. Laravel already does this for you.

All you need to do is review the docs on [retrieving request input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input), specifically the section titled "Retrieving JSON Input Values". If the data is posted with `Content-Type: application/json`, which according to your example it is, you can use `$request->input` to get the JSON data by key. So to get the data on the `version` key for example in that request in your controller, it should be in the return value of `$request->input('version')`.

Comment: That works fine $request->input('version'), but when I try to retrieve data -> observations ( $request->input('data.observations')) doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output exactly from `$request->input('data.observations')`? Also, check the output of `$request->all()` as suggested earlier to confirm what all data is accessible by the controller.